# Mapbox: add annotation only if the annotation is visible on screen

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have the data for my annotations stored in a database on Firebase. I've discovered that I can download data for 10,000 annotations and add these annotations to my map without much of a lag so long as the annotations do not have a custom view.

For my app however, I'm going to need to use custom views, each annotation view is an image composed of multiple image pieces. If I use custom views(even if the custom view is just a single UIImage), the app freezes up and eventually I receive the error "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue". My app has a minimum zoom level of 15 so users can mostly only see what is around them.

My goal is to download the annotation data for all the annotations within maybe 10 km of the user(I'll do this with geohashing although this is not the focus of this question). The map on the phone will only be able to view a span of land of about a km or so.

I then either only want to

```
 a) add annotations that are visible on the phone
```

or

```
b) only load the views for the annotations that are visible.
```

I want the annotations to be visible as soon as they are within the boundaries of the screen though, so that if a user is scrolling through the map, they see these annotations immediately.

---

I have this delegate function within my view controller that determines the view of each annotation, when I comment it out there is a slight delay is adding the annotations, but not a whole lot.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MGLUserLocation && mapView.userLocation != nil {
        let view = CurrentUserAnnoView(reuseIdentifier: currentUser.uid!)
        self.currentUserAnno = view
        return view
    }
    else if annotation is UserAnnotation{
        let anno = annotation as! UserAnnotation
        let auid = anno.reuseIdentifier //The anno uid
        if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: auid) {
            return annotationView
        } else {
            let annotationView = UserAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: auid, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45), annotation: annotation)
            annotationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            anno.view = annotationView
            return annotationView
        }
    }
    return MGLAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "ShouldntBeAssigned")  //Should never happen
}
```

---

**Example**

If you look at this youtube video, you can see that the annotations aren't always visible, and they only become visible as you zoom or move over them.
https://youtu.be/JWUFD48Od4M

---

**MapViewController**

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var newPostView: NewPostView!
    @IBOutlet var mapView: MGLMapView!
    var data: MapData?
    var currentUserAnno: CurrentUserAnnoView?
    var testCounter = 0

    let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: Database.database().reference().child("/users/core"))

    @IBAction func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        geoFire.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: 37.7853889, longitude: -122.4056973), forKey: "7")
        self.startup()
    }

    func startup(){
        if CLLocationManager.isOff(){
            let popup = UIAlertController(title: "Location Services are Disabled", message: "Please enable location services in your 'Settings -> Privacy' if you want to use this app", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            popup.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction) in
                self.startup()
            }))
            popup.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            self.mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
            self.data = MapData(delegate: self)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func newHidea(_ sender: Any) {
        newPostView.isHidden = false
    }


}

extension MapViewController: MGLMapViewDelegate{

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        print(testCounter)
        testCounter = testCounter + 1
        if annotation is MGLUserLocation && mapView.userLocation != nil {
            let view = CurrentUserAnnoView(reuseIdentifier: currentUser.uid!)
            self.currentUserAnno = view
            return view
        }
        else if annotation is UserAnnotation{
            let anno = annotation as! UserAnnotation
//            let auid = anno.reuseIdentifier //The anno uid
            if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "UserAnnotationView") {
                return annotationView
            } else {
                let annotationView = UserAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: "UserAnnotationView", size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45), annotation: annotation)
                annotationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                //anno.view = annotationView
                return annotationView
            }
        }
        return MGLAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "ShouldntBeAssigned")  //Should never happen
    }


    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, calloutViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLCalloutView? {
    /*The regular anno status box is replaced by one with buttons*/
        let annotationPoint = mapView.convert(annotation.coordinate, toPointTo: nil)
        let viewFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -10), size: CGSize(width: 180, height: 400))
        var cView: AnnoCalloutView
        if (annotation as! UserAnnotation).status != nil{
            cView =  StatusCallout(representedObject: annotation, frame: viewFrame, annotationPoint: annotationPoint)
        }else{
            cView = ProfileCallout(representedObject: annotation, frame: viewFrame, annotationPoint: annotationPoint)
        }
        return cView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        if (annotation is UserAnnotation) {
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }

    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)  // Hide the callout.
    }



}

//TODO: Check if there's a better method than a delegate to do this, since it's Model -> Controller
extension MapViewController: MapDataDelegate{
    func addAnnotation(_ anno: UserAnnotation) {
        self.mapView?.addAnnotation(anno)
    }
}
```

---

**UserAnnotation**

```
class UserAnnotation: NSObject, MGLAnnotation {

    //////////Ignore these, required for MGLAnnotation//////
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var status: Status?{
        didSet{
            //TODO: update annotation
        }
    }
    var reuseIdentifier: String
    var avatar: Avatar
    var uid: String

    //MARK: You could assign these when the profile is viewed once, so if they view it again you have it saved.
    var uName: String?
    var bio: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, avatar: Avatar, reuseIdentifier: String?, uid: String) {
//    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, reuseIdentifier uid: String?) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = "None"
        self.subtitle = "None"
        self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier!
        self.uid = uid
        self.avatar = avatar
        super.init()
//        self.setAvatar(avatar: avatar)
    }

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?){
        print("This shouldn't be printing")
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.uName = "ShouldntBeSet"
        self.title = "ShouldntBeSet"
        self.subtitle = "ShouldntBeSet"
        self.reuseIdentifier = "ShouldntBeAssigned"
        self.uid = "ShouldntBeAssigned"
        self.avatar = Avatar(withValues: [0])
    }
}
```

---

**UserAnnotationView**

```
class UserAnnotationView: MGLAnnotationView {

    var anno: UserAnnotation?
    var statusView: UITextView?
    var imageView: UIImageView?
    var avatarImage: UIImage{
        let ai = AvatarImage()
        ai.update(with: (anno?.avatar.values)!)
        return ai.image!
    }


    init(reuseIdentifier: String, size: CGSize, annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // Prevents view from changing size when view tilted
        scalesWithViewingDistance = false
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        self.anno = annotation as? UserAnnotation
        self.setUpImageView(frame: frame, size: size, annotation: annotation)
        if anno?.status != nil{
            self.createStatus(status: (anno?.status?.status)!)
        }
    }

    func reuseWithDifferentAnno(annotation: UserAnnotation){
        self.anno = annotation
        self.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "Will")
        //        let av = AvatarImage.newAvatar(values: (anno?.avatar.values)!)
//        self.imageView!.image = av.image
//        if anno?.status != nil{
//            self.createStatus(status: (anno?.status?.status)!)
//        }else{
//            if statusView != nil{
//                deleteStatus()
//            }
//        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func setUpImageView(frame: CGRect, size: CGSize, annotation: MGLAnnotation){
        self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        self.imageView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if annotation is UserAnnotation {
//            let av = AvatarImage.newAvatar(values: (anno?.avatar.values)!)
//            self.imageView!.image = av.image
            self.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "Will")

        }else{
            let image = UIImage()
            self.imageView!.image = image
        }
        addSubview(self.imageView!)
        imageViewConstraints(imageView: self.imageView!, size: size)
    }

    func setImage(to image: UIImage){
        self.imageView!.image = image
    }

    func createStatus(status: String){
        if (status == self.statusView?.text) && (self.subviews.contains(self.statusView!)){
            return
        }else if self.statusView != nil && self.subviews.contains(self.statusView!){
            deleteStatus()
        }
        self.statusView = UITextView()
        self.statusView!.text = status
        self.statusView!.isHidden = false
        self.adjustUITextViewHeight()
        self.statusView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.statusView!.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.statusView!.textAlignment = .center
        addSubview(self.statusView!)
        textViewConstraints(textView: self.statusView!, isAbove: self.imageView!)
    }

    func deleteStatus(){
        self.statusView?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.statusView = nil
    }

    private func adjustUITextViewHeight(){

        self.statusView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.statusView!.sizeToFit()
        self.statusView!.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    private func imageViewConstraints(imageView: UIImageView, size: CGSize){
        let widCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: size.width)
        let heightCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: size.height)
        let cenCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([cenCon, widCon, heightCon])
    }

    private func textViewConstraints(textView status: UITextView, isAbove imageView: UIImageView){
        let cenCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: status, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let botCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: status, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
        let widCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: status, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([cenCon, botCon, widCon])
    }

}
```

---

**MapData**

```
class MapData {
    var annotations = [String:UserAnnotation]()
    var updateTimer: Timer?
    var delegate: MapDataDelegate

    init(delegate: MapDataDelegate){
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.startTimer()
    }

    @objc func getUsers(){
        FBCore.getAllUsers(completion:{(users) in
            for child in users {
                let value = child.value as! NSDictionary
                self.getDataFor(user: value, whoseUidIs: child.key)
            }
        })
    }

    func getDataFor(user: NSDictionary, whoseUidIs annoid: String){
        if annoid != currentUser.uid! && (currentUser.blockedBy?[annoid] ?? false) != true && (currentUser.blocks?[annoid] ?? false) != true{
            guard let (coord, status, avatar) = FBCoreUser.get(forQryVal: user)
                else {return}
            if let anno = self.annotations[annoid]{
                anno.coordinate = coord
                if status != nil{// && anno.view!.isSelected == false {
                    if ((status?.isExpired)!){
                        anno.status = nil
                    }else{
                        anno.status = status
                    }
                }
                if avatar.values != anno.avatar.values{
                    anno.avatar = avatar
                }
            }else{
                let anno = UserAnnotation(coordinate: coord, avatar: avatar, reuseIdentifier: "UserAnnotation", uid: annoid)
                if status != nil{
                    if ((status?.isExpired)!){
                        anno.status = nil
                    }else{
                        anno.status = status
                    }
                }
                self.annotations[annoid] = anno
                //print(anno.reuseIdentifier)
                delegate.addAnnotation(anno)
            }
        }
    }

    func startTimer(){
        // Scheduling timer to Call the function "updateCounting" with the interval of 5 seconds
        if updateTimer != nil{
            updateTimer!.invalidate()
        }
        updateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(getUsers), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you create images in runtime or are those already available ones? And do you have ant kind of caching system to cache those images?

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan The images are a collection of UIImages that I have saved in Assets.xcassets, there's separate images for different body parts(i.e. an image for hair, an image for eyes,...) as chosen by the user, and no I don't believe I have any sort of cache, could you elaborate on that a bit more? I know a little bit about caches, but know nothing in terms of implementing it with iOS

Comment: Rather than querying images from assets everytime, you could query that and put it in cache when the image is needed for the first time. And from the next time you need an image, you could check if it is present in cache first and query from asset only if it is not present. You can use NSCache for caching images. Refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache

Comment: And the other most important aspect is the resolution of images you are using. Since you gonna show more number of images at the same time onscreen, if the images are of high resolution it would end up in memory issue. So, it would be better if you try to resize the images to a smaller resolution if they are of higher one.

Comment: @SubramanianMariappan Thanks, I'll likely need that stuff as well. If you look at this youtube video, you can see that the annotations aren't always visible, and they only become visible as you zoom or move over them. This is on the Facebook app which uses Mapbox, I feel like this is probably what I want, although I'm not too sure
https://youtu.be/JWUFD48Od4M

Comment: I think you are taking the wrong route to reduce your memory load. If a user heavily flips through your map & uses the zoom, you'll have the same memory problem. You need to aggregate your annotations (as a function of the zoom), not load them depending on your map width. See the App Periscope and similar to get a feel of it.

Comment: @Alex Which part is the wrong approach? In my app, each user is an annotation, the purpose is for users to see other users within their area, kind of like snapMap but it's not limited to seeing only friends, users can see anyone. That's the reason that I'm geohashing, because if the amount of users grows too large, it would be a massive amount of downloads to download every annotation.Is this part fine?

Also it looks like when I'm zoomed in super close and add the annotations, the map still freezes up if I'm using custom annotations, but doesn't freeze up if I'm using standard annotations

Comment: In your case, the wrong approach is to add all annotations pertaining to a map zoom, and let MapKit decide which to display. This is what you do in a/ and b/, even if you think you're not. That is because a user WILL eventually download all annotations through browsing, because the map boundaries are defined by the user zooming & position, and your app will eventually run out of memory, or will be very slow. If you have a lot of annotations (say >50k), you must use clustering. You can create your own clustering algorithm or use off the shelf ones. See below my response for an exhaustive answer

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell from your code it seems like you're not using reuseIdentifier properly.

The goal of the resueIdentifier and dequeuing views is to never have more views created that whats actually visible (or at least minimize it)

You use it to get views of the same type that you already created, but are not visible or needed anymore. So if your custom view has an UIImageView and a label and some layouts, you won't create it again, but reuse one that was already created.

Once you get a view back that is available you assign the properties that change from annotation to annotation without creating another view.

What this means is that it doesn't matter if you downloaded 10,000 or 100,000 annotations, the number of views created for the map will never be larger than the number of views visible on the screen.

Saying that, your code should look something like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MGLUserLocation && mapView.userLocation != nil {
        let view = CurrentUserAnnoView(reuseIdentifier: "userLocation")
        self.currentUserAnno = view
        return view
    }
    else if annotation is UserAnnotation{
        let anno = annotation as! UserAnnotation
        let reuseIdentifier = "myCustomAnnotationView"
        if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) {
        // set view properties for current annotation before returing
            annotationView.image = anno.image
            annotationView.name = anno.name // etc.
            return annotationView
        } else {
            let annotationView = UserAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45), annotation: annotation)
            annotationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//          anno.view = annotationView // this is strange, not sure if it makes sense
            annotationView.image = anno.image // set annotation view properties
            annotationView.name = anno.name // etc.
            return annotationView
        }
    }
    return MGLAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "ShouldntBeAssigned")  //Should never happen
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have some functions in the init for my UserAnnotationView that do things like create a text view above the annotation if the annotation has some text describing it. Would I also need to call these functions after setting annotationView.image and annotationView.name. In other words must I run all code that would make a difference between the two annotation views?

Comment: @sam in short yes. Every property that is different between one view and the other needs to be set after dequeuing the cell. Think of dequeuing as just another way to create a brand new custom view, which means you need to set all its properties

Comment: @Alex clustering is a great idea and definitely a worthy optimization, I just don't think its the problem here, and if clustering would be implemented without properly using dequeuing the same performance issues will come up. Just read about how to use a UITableView, this is the exact same thing.

Comment: So I'm at a min zoom of 15, and the only annotation visible is the annotation for the user, but the app still freezes up with 10,000 annotations that are placed at random coordinates all over the world. I implemented what your talking about but it still crashes, is there something I'm doing wrong? The annotations aren't even visible.

Comment: @Sam it's a little hard to debug this way, but maybe a couple of things: 1. are you still doing this anno.view = annotationView? 2. Put a counter and print everytime you enter view for annotation. I seriously doubt that this function is called more than once

Comment: It calls 1031 times before it crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203171/discussion-between-ron-srebro-and-sam).

Comment: It's on Github now if you want to take a look, I posted the link in the discussion

Comment: @Sam MapKit takes care of displaying the annotations that are visible. If you started at min zoom (that is max number of visible annotations), and zoomed in to max zoom (only one annotation left to see), the runtime still handles 10k annotations, while only displaying one. You save on GPU memory, but the app remains slow because the app memory foot print is still very high, and it can crash as well. You can 1/remove then add relevant annotations when the zoom changes (very bad idea) 2/ Use clustering which will guaranty that an arbitrary max number of annotations will be displayed.

Comment: @RonSrebro : " the same performance issues will come up". Nope. As per Mapbox api, Clusterization is implemented on a surface area basis (cluster radius), not a number of annotations per cluster, therefore this guarantees that the number of displayed annotations is bounded. In Mapbox algorithm, it seems that the waypoints are first added to a b-tree. There's a small performance hit at first, but after that retrieval is very fast (that is, there's no need to enumerate all annotations to pick new clusters as the zoom changes). I've used clusterization to deal with 100s of waypoints, it works.

Comment: @RonSrebro Hey, so I'm trying to do something similar in `React` now and having trouble looking stuff up. Do you have any terminology for this concept? All I can really see is the word `dequeuing` to describe this concept in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox has delegate methods for did change and will change region (take your pick).

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)
```

when the region changes you need to set the annotations on the map to the annotations inside that region.  The easiest way to do it seems to be to convert the coordinates to the mapView's space and then check if they are in the mapView's bounds.

```
let newAnnotations = allAnnotations.filter { annotation in
  let point = mapView.convert(annotation.coordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
  return mapView.bounds.contains(point)
}
if let existingAnnotations = mapView.annotations {
  mapView.removeAnnotations(existingAnnotations)
}
mapView.addAnnotations(newAnnotations)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is a common issue when dealing with a large number of point, and i'm afraid that your approach is not going to help you. This is especially true if/when a user makes a heavy use of your map, zooming from min to max zooms. All points will be downloaded, and you'll fall into the same problem. Note: If you choose to remove annotations as the user zooms out, that's called clustering, which is what the solutions below provide, out of the box (a.k.a don't reinvent the wheel)

See the [post](https://blog.mapbox.com/clustering-millions-of-points-on-a-map-with-supercluster-272046ec5c97) by Mapbox on that topic, it's for GL JS, but the same reasoning applies in your case. For iOS, mapbox has released a [clustering api](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering/), I haven't tried it, but it seems to do the job. There's also an extensive code example you could get inspiration from. I won't reproduce it here, for obvious reasons, just a pic of the final result, so you can figure out if that's what you need.

[image: clustering datapoints]

There is also plenty of code on github to do that, see [here](https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit)

in the mapbox code

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson")!)
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts",
url: url,
options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])
style.addSource(source)
[...]
}
```

replace the lines:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ports", ofType: "geojson")!)
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts",
url: url, options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])
```

by:

```
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "my points",
shapes: shapes, options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])
```

where `shapes` is [MGLShape], created from your waypoints. MGLShape is derived from Annotations using `MGLShape : NSObject <MGLAnnotation, NSSecureCoding>`, see [here](https://mapbox.github.io/mapbox-gl-native/macos/0.5.1/Classes/MGLShape.html). See also [here](https://mapbox.github.io/mapbox-gl-native/macos/0.5.1/Classes/MGLShapeSource.html) for MGLShapeSource protoypes.

You will have to create a method, to instantiate those shapes, from your waypoints, or in short:

```
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "my points",
shapes: self.createShapes(from:annotations), options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])
```

Comment: What are the obvious reasons that you won't reproduce it here?

Comment: The examples are pretty confusing to me, I've uploaded the main files that deal with my map and annotaitons. Do you know how I would add clustering to them?

Comment: @sam the obvious reason not to reproduce it here is because it's extensively described and explained on MapBox Website, so it would be redundant to print it verbatim :p. Have you tried this code : https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit, it's iOS ready, with examples, you just have to plug your mapbox key. Also you can copy/paste the mapbox code here https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering/ and create a temporary view in your app, just to test drive their api.

Comment: @Sam i added some code snippets, hope this helps. Also, when calling self.createShapes(from:annotations), you can pass ALL of your 10k annotations, MapBox framework will take care of the rest. Note2: If I remember correctly, you don't need to keep a reference to the original annotations, you can delete the annotations array once they are passed to MapBox framework, this will save your plenty of memory.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following this right,

We can ignore the dataset size issue because it will be reduced by only showing annotations for their immediate vicinity.

For those you will show, they work fine when they are just annotations, but when you give them a custom view they are slow to appear and disappear.

By looking at the video, this seems to simply be an animation issue. The view-annotations are being faded in and out. If you don't want that effect then turn off that animation.

I can't tell from the code snippet where that animation might be specified, but it should be easy to locate. For example, several of the MLG apis have an (animated: Boolean) property where you can specify false.