# Infinite scrolling React grid which only renders the visible grid tiles, but recycles them to show "new" tiles: Similar to React Native FlatList

Tags: reactjs, listview, css-grid, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist

**Problem Explanation**

I have grid with a bunch of square tiles in it(about 120).
If only 8 tiles are visible at a time, then I only want to render about 16 tiles.

- The 8 visible tiles, plus a buffer

When scrolling, when the top 4 or so tiles scroll off the screen, these tiles would be recycled, have the information in them replaced with the information for next 4 tiles, and then be placed in the buffer so that they are displayed when the user scrolls a bit more.

This really optimizes the component if you have a lot of tiles, because you only need to render the ones that are visible, plus a buffer.

---

**Further Reference**

This kind of concept is implemented in [React Native's Flatlist](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist), as well as [Recycler View](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview). I have seen some node modules
which look like a `react.js` version of a `Flatlist`, but I do not think most of these will work, because I am trying to implement this concept using a `CSS Grid` type layout.

I have also heard this problem described as [dequeuing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59062821/6331353)

---

**Best online solution**

After looking at a lot of node modules, I have found an example node module of this concept which uses a grid type layout called [InfiniteScrollGrid](https://github.com/ggordan/react-infinite-grid), which has a [live demo](https://ggordan.com/post/react-infinite-grid.html). The main problem with this node module is that it is old, unmaintained, uses old React styles, has security vulnerabilities, and I couldn't even get it to compile.

One other issue is that I would like the individual tiles to **maintain their original width:height** ratio as the user changes the width of their web browser

---

**Attempted Solution**

Below I have tried to implement the functionality of the node module myself using `hooks`. I've tried my best to replicate it, but feel like I haven't fully wrapped my head around all the code in that node module.

**There is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-smoke-enidm?file=/src/components/InfiniteScrollGrid/index.js) and [github repo](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/InfiniteScrollGrid) for the example below.**

- **Note:** For some reason the codesandbox has some errors that do not appear locally even though I forked the sandbox from the Github

**InfiniteScrollGrid.js**

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, memo} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Item from './Item';

//Inifinately scrolling grid, that only renders as many items as visible on the screen
//Based on React Native FlatList, and this Github Repo https://github.com/ggordan/react-infinite-grid
const InfiniteScrollGrid =  memo(({
    buffer = 10,
    padding = 10,
    entries = [],
    height = 250,
    width = 250,
    wrapHeight,
    lazyCallback,
    renderRangeCallback
}) => {

    if (!entries.length) return null;

    const itemHeightConst = height + (2 * padding);
    const itemWidthConst = width + (2 * padding);

    const wrapper = useRef();
    const grid = useRef();
    const [initiatedLazyload, setInitiatedLazyload] = useState(false);
    const [numEntries, setNumEntries] = useState(entries.length);
    const [minHeight, setMinHeight] = useState(2);
    const [minItemIndex, setMinItemIndex] = useState(0);
    const [maxItemIndex, setMaxItemIndex] = useState(100);
    const [wrapperHeight, setWrapperHeight] = useState(wrapHeight);

    const [itemHeight, setItemHeight] = useState(itemHeightConst);
    const [itemWidth, setItemWidth] = useState(itemHeightConst);
    const [itemGridWidth, setItemGridWidth] = useState(0);
    const [itemsPerRow, setItemsPerRow] = useState(2);

    const [initiatedLazyLoad, setInitiatedLazyLoad] = useState(false);

    const gridHeight = Math.floor(entries.length / itemsPerRow) * itemHeight;
    const getItemsPerRow = Math.floor(grid?.current?.clientWidth / itemWidthConst);
    const numVisibleRows = Math.ceil(wrapper?.current?.height / itemHeight);
    const scrolledPastRows = Math.floor((grid?.current?.height - grid?.current?.bottom) / itemHeight);

    const [scrollOffset, setScrollOffset] = useState('');

    const styles = {
        wrapper: {
            maxHeight: grid?.current?.clientHeight,
            overflowY: 'scroll',
            width: '100%',
            height: wrapperHeight,
            WebkitOverflowScrolling: true
        },
        grid: {
            position: 'relative',
            marginTop: padding,
            marginLeft: padding,
            minHeight: grid?.current?.clientHeight
        }
    };

    const totalRows = () => {
        const scrolledPastHeight = (entries.length / itemsPerRow) * itemHeightConst;
        return scrolledPastHeight < 0 ? 0 : scrolledPastHeight;
    };

    const visibleIndexes = () => {

        // The number of rows that the user has scrolled past
        let scrolledPast = Math.max((scrolledPastRows * itemsPerRow), 0);
        let min = Math.max((scrolledPast - itemsPerRow), 0);

        let bufferRows = numVisibleRows + buffer;
        let max = min(scrolledPast + (itemsPerRow * bufferRows), entries.length);

        setMinItemIndex(min);
        setMaxItemIndex(max);
    };

    const updateItemDimensions = () => {
        // setItemHeight(itemHeightConst);
        // setItemWidth(itemWidthConst);
        setItemGridWidth(grid?.current?.width);
        setItemsPerRow(getItemsPerRow());
        setMinHeight(totalRows());
    };

    const scrollListener = (event) => {
        clearTimeout(scrollOffset);
        setScrollOffset(setTimeout(() => visibleIndexes(), 10));
    };

    useEffect(() => {

        const resizeListener = () => {
            if (!wrapperHeight) setWrapperHeight(window?.innerHeight);
            updateItemDimensions();
            visibleIndexes();
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
        updateItemDimensions();
        visibleIndexes();
        return window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {       //TODO: May need to disable on the first render
        if (!initiatedLazyload && (maxItemIndex === entries.length) && lazyCallback) {
            setInitiatedLazyLoad(true);
            lazyCallback(maxItemIndex);
        };
    }, [minItemIndex, maxItemIndex]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (entries.length > numEntries) {
            setInitiatedLazyLoad(false);
            setNumEntries(entries.length);
        };
        visibleIndexes();
    }, [entries]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof renderRangeCallback === 'function') {
            renderRangeCallback(minItemIndex, maxItemIndex);    //TODO: What is this about
        };
    }, [buffer, padding, entries, height, width, wrapHeight, lazyCallback, renderRangeCallback, initiatedLazyload, numEntries, minHeight, minItemIndex, maxItemIndex, wrapperHeight, itemHeight, itemWidth, itemGridWidth, itemsPerRow, initiatedLazyLoad]);    //What are prev props and prev state

    return (
        <div
            ref={wrapper}
            className='infinite-grid-wrapper'
            onScroll={scrollListener}
            style={styles.wrapper}
        >
            <div ref={grid} className='infinite-grid' style={styles.grid}>
                {entries.slice(minItemIndex, maxItemIndex).map((entry, i) => (
                    <Item
                        key={`item-${i}`}
                        index={minItemIndex + i}
                        padding={padding}
                        width={itemWidth}
                        height={itemHeight}
                        itemsPerRow={itemsPerRow}
                        data={entry}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );

});

InfiniteScrollGrid.propTypes = {
    buffer: PropTypes.number,
    padding: PropTypes.number,
    entries: PropTypes.number,
    height: PropTypes.number,
    width: PropTypes.number,
    wrapHeight: PropTypes.number,
    lazyCallback: PropTypes.func,
    renderRangeCallback: PropTypes.func
};

export default InfiniteScrollGrid;
```

**Item.js**

```js
import React, {memo} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Item = memo(({width, itemsPerRow, index, height, padding, data}) => {

    const style = {
        width: (width / itemsPerRow) - padding,
        height: height - padding,
        left: (index % itemsPerRow) * (width / itemsPerRow),
        top: Math.floor((index / itemsPerRow) * height),
        position: 'absolute'
    };

    return (
        <div style={style} className="item">
            <div>{data}</div>
        </div>
    );
});

Item.propTypes = {
    width: PropTypes.number,
    itemsPerRow: PropTypes.number,
    index: PropTypes.number,
    height: PropTypes.number,
    padding: PropTypes.number,
    data: PropTypes.any
};

export default Item;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Example Usage**

```js
import React from 'react';
import InfiniteScrollGrid from './index';

const ExampleItem = ({index}) => (
    <div className='example'>
        This is {index}
    </div>
);

export default () => {
 
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        items.push(<ExampleItem index={i} />);
    };

    const lazyCallback = (index) => {
        console.log(index);
    };
    
    return (
        <InfiniteScrollGrid entries={items} wrapperHeight={400} lazyCallback={lazyCallback} />
    );
};
```

---

I would like a working solution of this infinately scrolling grid component

Comment: You're getting the 'useEffect conditionally' error because you have `if (!entries.length) return null;` at the start of InfiniteScrollGrid.  You need to ensure there are no return statements before any `useX` calls in your function component to avoid the error.

Comment: @BenClayton Thank you! I've updated the sandbox and github to fix that part

Comment: Did you try the `react-window` package? https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

Comment: Would you accept an answer with packages like `react-window`?

Comment: @0stone0 I'll always accept the best answer available, or at least give the bounty to it

Comment: @0stone0 So yeah if you post an answer with `react-window` I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to look into virtualization. `react-virtualized` and `react-window` are quite popular options

Answer (score 0):

What you want is often refered as `windowing`.

I would recommand [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) created by main React engineer [Brian Vaughn](https://github.com/bvaughn).

[Here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html#deep-dive-video)'s a example where he's using it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "react-virtualized" or something similar will help you. You are in an app and if you want to process a lot of data, you have to load it first. Loading large amounts of data and then displaying them in a virtual list is not a real scenario. What you need is an extended FlatList. The normal FlatList has a "threshold" value and an "onEndReached" method, which is sufficient to expand the list. The list fills up from time to time and the application slower, so you need an additional "threshold" value and an "onStartReached" method. The "threshold" value is to be selected based on the loading time and the "on ... Reached" method loads a reasonable amount of data. Since you are not alone with this problem, there are already finished implementations that you can use as a guide. I say as guide because we all only cook with water. I searched for "bi-directional infinite scroll" on google and [found it](https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-bidirectional-infinite-scroll). I highly recommend using the standard components of react native and extend them.

Happy Programming!

Comment: I'm talking about regular react, not react native